# Partial Derivatives Continuous does not guarantee Gradient Function continuous

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Just want to check my understanding that partial derivatives continuous does not mean that the gradient function $\nabla f$ is continuous. Is that correct?

E.g. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ continuous does not necessarily mean that $\nabla f=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$ is continuous.

I concluded that based on "Continuity in each argument is not sufficient for multivariate continuity".

Question 2) What conditions guarantee that $\nabla f$ is continuous?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $\nabla f$ is continuous. Note that:

\begin{align*}
 || \nabla f(x,y) - \nabla f(x_0,y_0)||^2 = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)- \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0))^2 + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)- \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0))^2
\end{align*}
Thus continuity of the partial derivatives imply that the gradient is continuous.

Your quote says something different too. It says that continuity in x and y resp. does not imply continuity in $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$. This makes perfect sence, in $\mathbb R^2$ you can approach a point from many more directions that just parallel along the $x$- and $y$-axis.

**DETAILS:**
Let $\epsilon >0$ be fixed. Then by continuity of the partial derivatives we know there exist $\delta_1 >0$ and $\delta_2>0$ so that:

\begin{align*}
 ||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|| <\delta_1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)- \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{8}}\\
||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|| <\delta_2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)- \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{8}}
\end{align*}

Now let $\delta = \min \{\delta_1, \delta_2 \}$. Now we have that:

\begin{align*}
 || \nabla f(x,y) - \nabla f(x_0,y_0)||^2 &= (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)- \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0))^2 + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)- \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0))^2\\
 & < \frac{2\epsilon^2}{8} = \frac{\epsilon^2}{4}.
\end{align*}
Thus we have:
\begin{align*}
 || \nabla f(x,y) - \nabla f(x_0,y_0)|| < \frac{\epsilon}{2},
\end{align*}
as required.

Answer (score 2):

Any vector-valued function ${\bf g}=(g_1,\ldots,g_m)$ is continuous (at some point $p$ or overall) **iff** all its component functions $g_i$ are continuous. This is an immediate consequence of the following inequalities for vectors ${\bf x}$, ${\bf y}$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$:
$$|x_i-y_i|\leq|{\bf x}-{\bf y}|\leq\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k-y_k|\ .$$
In particular ${\bf g}:=\nabla f$ is continuous iff all coordinates ${\partial f\over\partial x_k}$ of $\nabla f$ are continuous.

Comment: This answer conflates the Jacobian with the Gradient. If the gradient exists, it is equal to the Jacobian. But it's possible for the Jacobian to exist, without the gradient existing. The theorem is still true, but it's not this trivial.

Answer (score 2):

One way things can go wrong is if the partial derivatives exist but the gradient does not. For instance, $$ f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} \dfrac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} & \text{if }(x,y) \not= (0,0) \\ 0 & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0) \end{array} \right.$$ 
has the property that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist and are continuous at all points $(x,y)$, but $f$ has no gradient at the origin as it fails even to be continuous there.

It is for this reason that writing $\nabla f = ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$ requires a small amount of caution.

Comment: But if all partial derivatives exist and are continuous everywhere doesn't it follow that f is differentiable in any point and therefore also continuous?

Comment: Yes, this is incorrect. In this example, the partials exist but are not continuous at (0, 0). The partials are each 0 at (0, 0), but the partials in the neighborhood of (0, 0) take on many different values.

When the partials exist and are continuous, f is continuously differentiable.